# Is there some trick to getting aplay audio output working?

Tags: raspbian, audio

I have recorded a .wav file using the command:

```
arecord test.wav
```

But when I try to play it, there is no sound output. It's like the raspberry pi is stuck on mute. I initially thought that my microphone was defective, but I sent the wav file to my desktop and played it, and it definitely is not empty.

The audio on my raspberry pi works when I run the hello_audio.bin located in
        /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_audio
And it played a noise through my headphones, so I know it's not my headphones.

Comment: check the levels in alsamixer

Comment: For Pebble V3 USB speakers this instructions worked for me https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/usb-audio-cards-with-a-raspberry-pi.pdf

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this could be happening.

**Possible Problem #1:** Wrong RasPi hardware audio output selected (auto vs. HDMI vs. headphone/pwm out)

**Solution:** Force selection of the correct hardware.

```
amixer cset numid=3 0 # automatic detection (not always reliable) 
amixer cset numid=3 1 # force headphone (PWM) output
amixer cset numid=3 2 # force HDMI output
```

I like to put these as aliases in my `.bashrc` file so I don't have to remember the commands:

```
alias use-audio-auto="amixer cset numid=3 0" # auto
alias use-audio-headphones="amixer cset numid=3 1" # headphones
alias use-audio-hdmi="amixer cset numid=3 2" # hdmi
```

---

**Possible Problem #2:** Misconfigured ALSA subsystem / misconfigured `.asoundrc`

**Solution:** Make sure ALSA is configured correctly with good defaults for the RasPi hardware. The `/home/pi/.asoundrc` file should contain:

```
pcm.mmap0 {
    type mmap_emul;
    slave {
      pcm "hw:0,0";
    }
}

pcm.!default {
   type hw;
   card 0;
}

ctl.!default {
   type hw;
   card 0;
}
```

---

**Possible Problem #3:** Wrong hardware output device chosen by `aplay`

**Solution:** Check what devices are available using `aplay -l`

Run `aplay -l` to list playback devices detected, you should see something like this that references `bcm2835`:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If you're trying to test the headphone out, you'd force usage of it with:

```
aplay -Dhw:0,0 test.wav # 'try playing test.wav using hardware card 0, subdevice 0 (headphones)
```

Then, if you'd like to change the default for your Raspberry Pi, adjust your `.asoundrc` file to use the right hardware card index #.

---

**Possible Problem 4:** Your sound is simply muted/too low and you need to turn it up.

**Solution:** Make sure `alsa-utils` is installed and run `alsamixer`

```
sudo apt-get install -y alsa-utils
alsamixer
```

Then use the F1-F6 keys and UI to push up the volume.

[image: alsamixer]

Use the arrow keys to jack up the volume and quit.

To save what you changed in `alsamixer` as defaults, do:

```
sudo alsactl store 0
```

---

Hope that helps! Peace.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I have no idea what installation decided to mute and turn down my RetroPie volume all the way but I had no idea about this alsamixer command!  You saved me from reimaging my Raspberry Pi :D

Comment: @ChrisPrime no problem ;)

Comment: I think the `aplay` command needs a `:` in @Drew's answer. I think it should be:
```
aplay -Dhw:0,0 test.wav # 'try playing test.wav using hardware card 0, subdevice 0 (headphones)
```
Actually I'm pretty confident it should be that. Otherwise a great answer!

Comment: @nomadic_squirrel that is correct :) I've tweaked the answer, thanks!